# Database Optimization of a Giveaway Website Using Django

Tags: python, django, database

Hello everything is fine? So, the old project that is a "raffle" site has a chronic problem which is the use of up to 1000% of the CPU that is an AMD Ryzen 9 with 16 cores at high peaks of site usage. The total responsible for this enormous use is the database due to its lack of architecture/optimization. The challenge is: Solve this and make the site fast and accessible.

For that, I'll use Django and thought of some ways to solve this, among them, here's a possible solution.

`models.py` from the app `raffle`

```
class Raffle(models.Model):
    ...
    amount_of_numbers = models,PositiveInteger(default=100000)
```

The system will define the total number of tickets or the user and with these numbers, in the `save` method I will create 50-100 .txt files with numbers from 1 to 100000 without repetitions to avoid adding repeated numbers and causing " harmful queries"

```
import fcntl

with open('arquivo.txt', 'r') as arquivo:
    fcntl.flock(arquivo, fcntl.LOCK_EX)
    ...
    fcntl.flock(arquivo, fcntl.LOCK_UN)
```

I will use the a lib **fcntl** to guarantee that only one user has access to that list of numbers (that's why several lists) and avoid having to check repeated numbers in the database and after finishing the process, I will release the modified file (without the numbers added in the database) for the use of another user.

This is where "The Cat Jump" comes in, instead of adding 300, 600 or 1000 tickets one by one to a database like on the previous site. I tested adding 300 numbers in the ORM which took 32 seconds which is sendable. The tickets would be added to a dictionary and placed in the database all at once and would require 32x less time.

The final question: Is this a good solution? If so, is there any way to improve it? If not, is there anything better than this?

Thank you to everyone who takes the time to try to help me! :)

Comment: Why do you not handle everything with the database? This is much faster than handling files. With [bulk_create()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) you are able to insert a lot of objects with a single db query.

Comment: @Marco I didn't know about this function and I loved it. Instead of just iterating and adding one by one, I can use bulk_creat. One other issue I forgot to mention. The numbers need to be random. In this case, could I save the unused numbers in some file or is there another way to know without costs to the database?